# Auto-Generate id in ember-data with Local Storage Adapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

i need a way to generating id for new  record that added to store . I am using [local storage adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/). and searching for some way and find functions like in local storage adapter :

```
generateIdForRecord: function () {
    return Math.random().toString(32).slice(2).substr(0, 5);
}
```

but the the problem with this function is this function create ids in string , I am need auto increment id in integer scope. like 1 or 2 or 2000 and if new record added the id is maximum of ids in record plus 1. I need doing this in client side not server.

Comment: did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a ‍‍‍`counter-type` `id`, you can always do what fixture_adapter is doing, which is to have a variable called `counter` and increment it every time (see [here](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.12/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L127)).

But then, what happens if a record gets deleted? Do you want to have another new record that has an id of an old deleted record? And if instead you have some sort of a global counter that ALWAYS increments by 1, which would account for the issue I am mentioning - then you are anyways just assigning pretty much random ids, so why not go with the approach of a generating random ids, which is where you started from? :)